# VB passing Parameter Value ByRef does not change value until Method exits?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, parameter-passing, inotifypropertychanged

I have a Class in .Net Entity Framework which implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I have found an interesting problem in that my property changed setter fires a notification event, but the value of the change is not visible until the setter exits.

I implemented the following to test if a property value has changed, set the new value and then notify interested parties of the change:

```
Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, 
         e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

'' This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(PropertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName))
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Sets the specified property to a value and raises an event if the property has changed.
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T">Type of the destination field</typeparam>
''' <param name="field">Destination Field to check/update</param>
''' <param name="value">Field is to be set to this value, if it has not changed.</param>
''' <param name="PropertyName">Optional property name - filled in by compiler if left blank.</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Protected Function SetProperty(Of T)(ByRef field As T, value As T, _
                                     PropertyName As String, _
                                     Optional SupressEvent As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    If Not EqualityComparer(Of T).Default.Equals(field, value) Then
        field = value
        If Not SupressEvent Then NotifyPropertyChanged(PropertyName)
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

The property itself calls the SetProperty as follows:

```
Public Property AccruedShares As Decimal
    Get
        Return Me.AccruedSharesValue
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        SetProperty(Of Decimal)(Me.AccruedSharesValue, value, "AccruedShares", Loading)
    End Set
End Property
```

The problem is that setting a value of say 10 and calling the SetProperty results in a notification to a number of other methods, but the value of the property does not change until the SetProperty exits and returns back to the set. e.g. Setting a watch on AccruedSharesValue shows a value of 0.  When the event fires, all of the other methods see a value of 0 and it does not change to 10 until the code steps out of the SetProperty method.  This is completely contrary to how I see passing values by ref working.  ByRef should immediately change the value of the passed variable, not after the method exits.

Does anyone have any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: I cannot duplicate the problem.  The new value is seen *in* the change event for several properties. Maybe the problem is further downstream?  I have to say though that is a rather odd helper function.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 and .Net 4 in case that makes a difference.  I have run this several times, with a watch set on the AccruedSharesValue in the entity.  The 'field=value' statement executes and the value of the watched variable does not change.  Only after I step out of the SetProperty method, does the value change.  I am wondering if using a generic method somehow changes the setting of the reference value?  Perhaps it takes the referred value off the stack only when the method returns?

Comment: Your change event runs before you exit the setter; what is it there?  If the watch variable is grayed out it means that the var is out of scope and the value is "stale".  This would *seem* to be the case for a variable declared outside the Class with the setter.  Rather than a watch var see what the prop vals are in the PropertyChanged event

Comment: I ran into the exact same error today while trying to create the exact same functionality (change properties and run `PropertyChanged`). It seems that this method only works when it is being called with the exact same type as the property. When you change types halfway the referenced variable will only change when the method exits. I would call it a bug because it does not work as expected. How did you "fix" this? Call `PropertyChanged` outside of the `SetProperty` I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a short block of code:

```
    Public Property Population As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.PopulationValue
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            SetProperty(Of Integer)(Me.PopulationValue, value, "Population")
        End Set
    End Property
```

And then checked the disassembled listing:

```
.method public specialname instance void 
    set_Population(int32 'value') cil managed
{
  // Code size       31 (0x1f)
  .maxstack  5
  .locals init ([0] int32 VB$t_i4$S0)
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  callvirt   instance int32 Armada.DataModels.City::get_PopulationValue()
  IL_0007:  stloc.0
  IL_0008:  ldloca.s   VB$t_i4$S0
  IL_000a:  ldarg.1
  IL_000b:  ldstr      "Population"
  IL_0010:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0011:  callvirt   instance bool Armada.DataModels.City::SetProperty<int32>(!!0&,
                                                                                !!0,
                                                                                string,
                                                                                bool)
  IL_0016:  pop
  IL_0017:  ldarg.0
  IL_0018:  ldloc.0
  IL_0019:  callvirt   instance void Armada.DataModels.City::set_PopulationValue(int32)
  IL_001e:  ret
} // end of method City::set_Population
```

Apparently from the above code, the compiler pops a return value from the stack and then assigns it to the my value, after the call returns from the SetProperty at line IL_0019.  Again this only seems to happen with a generic method.  I have not seen this behaviour with normal methods.

I really think this should be labelled a Microsoft bug?

Answer (score 1):

I really, *really*, ***really*** appreciate you figuring that out from the IL.  I was able to stop pulling out my hair thinking it was my code and write some focused tests.

### To reproduce this:

Put this [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in a new WPF project (or whatever). Put breakpoints on each `End Sub` and examine your `locals` window.

```
Class ObjectWithName
    Public Property Name As String
End Class

Class MainWindow
    Private myClassLevelString = "Intitial"
    Private myClassLevelObject As New ObjectWithName() With {.Name = "Initial"}

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        'Group 1
        Generic(myClassLevelString, "Generic")
        NonGenericStrings(myClassLevelString, "NonGenericStrings")
        NonGenericObjects(myClassLevelString, "NonGenericObjects")

        'Group 2
        Generic(myClassLevelObject.Name, "Generic")
        NonGenericStrings(myClassLevelObject.Name, "NonGenericStrings")
        NonGenericObjects(myClassLevelObject.Name, "NonGenericObjects")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Generic(Of T)(ByRef p1 As T, p2 As T)
        p1 = p2
        Dim Group1 = myClassLevelString
        Dim Group2 = myClassLevelObject.Name
        ' At this point:
        ' p1 = "Generic"
        ' Group1 = "Generic"
        ' Group2 = "Initial"
    End Sub

    Private Sub NonGenericStrings(ByRef p1 As String, p2 As String)
        p1 = p2
        Dim Group1 = myClassLevelString
        Dim Group2 = myClassLevelObject.Name
        ' At this point:
        ' p1 = "NonGenericStrings"
        ' Group1 = "Generic" <-- This is NOT a typo!
        ' Group2 = "Generic"
    End Sub

    Private Sub NonGenericObjects(ByRef p1 As Object, p2 As Object)
        p1 = p2
        Dim Group1 = myClassLevelString
        Dim Group2 = myClassLevelObject.Name
        ' At this point:
        ' p1 = "NonGenericObjects"
        ' Group1 = "NonGenericObjects" <-- This is not a typo either.
        ' Group2 = "NonGenericStrings"
    End Sub
End Class
```

## Observations

1. It is not a Generic vs. Non-Generic problem.
2. It might be a problem* with passing other objects' properties in (i.e. `myClassLevelObject.Name`) vs. `Me`'s properties (i.e. `myClassLevelString`).
3. Other objects' properties behave consistently, albeit frustratingly, by "lagging" the class-level variable's update until the function returns.
4. `Me`' properties behave **inconsistently**.

   - When setting `ByRef T`s and `ByRef Object`s, the class-level variable changes immediately.
   - When setting `ByRef String`s, the value "lags" until the return from the function.

<sub>* I say "might be a problem" because I'm *sure* it is not a bug.  We probably just do not understand enough about ... whatever area this falls into!</sub>

Comment: Very nice test example.  I wonder if anybody from Microsoft is reading over here, or if you should post in on the MSDN forum.

Answer (score 0):

It is confirmed again with .Net 4.6, this behavior is still here.

I am converting some legacy VB6 source codes to .Net. The original codes uses ByRef everywhere (not intended to change this variable, the old programmers just liked to use ByRef).

For example, in VB6, the follow works,

```
Function GetNewString(ByRef old As String) As String
    return old & "NEW"
End Function

Dim rs As ADO.RecordSet
Call GetNewString(rs.Fields("column1").Value)
```

Although it's dumb code, it works.

However, if you convert everything to VB.Net, and still use the above code, it still works except that the recordset (and database) is updated! It's like

```
' To repalce ADO.RecordSet (internally uses DataTable / SqlConnection / OdbcConnection)
Dim rs As MyRecordSet 
GetNewString(rs.Fields("column1").Value) ' Database will be updated once here!

Function GetNewString(ByRef old As String) As String
    ' This is what .Net added automatically.
    ' It means rs.Fields("column1").Value = old so the database will be updated!
    old = old  
    return old & "NEW"
End Function
```

I have to manually change all such ByRef to ByVal.

Comment: Your VB6 example does not work because `return` throws a syntax error. That is not the way how functions work in VB6. I fixed the code and tested it. Then I tested the adapted code in .NET and it worked as expected. So I do not think this is the same problem.